# Why does memcpy change the last element of original array?

Tags: c

I encountered a weird bug in this code:

```
int *a = (int*) malloc(N*sizeof(int));  // allocate array
int i;
for (i=2; i<=N; i++)
{
  a[i] = i;
}

int *b = (int*) malloc(N*sizeof(int));
memcpy(b, a, N*sizeof(b));
```

If I were to print out array a, output = 2,3,...,19 0

Whereas the expected output should have been 2,3,...,19,20.

Copying the array onto b strangely affected the last element.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue: not sure you should be using `N*sizeof(b)` in your last line. `sizeof(b)` will give you the size of an int pointer, whereas you want the size of an int.

Comment: I was expecting `BAD_ACCESS` becasue of `i<=N`

Comment: If I used sizeof(b), I get error. If used sizeof(int),  the output is still the same

Comment: `sizeof(b)` could be either 4 bytes(i686) or 8 bytes(x86_64), you should go for `sizeof(int)`

Comment: @John J  The presented code does not make any sense. So it is useless to discuss why something is changed.

Comment: @user7859067: `sizeof *b` is the best option. `sizeof b` is wrong and `sizeof(int)` will become wrong when `b` is changed to a `uint64_t`. That's true in both the malloc and the memcpy.

Answer (score 2):

An array of `N` elements has valid indexes `0`, `1`,  ..., `N - 1`. Your final loop round accesses `a[N]`, which is out of bounds and has undefined behaviour.

Comment: That, and his `memset` is going to go past the end on 64-bit systems with 32-bit integers.